# mysqldump: got error 1049: unknown database `phpmyadmin`

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

El año pasado trabajaba con phpmyadmin para la creación de bases de datos para proyectos simples de creación de páginas web en localhost. Este año dichas páginas las programo desde el workbench; al descargar dicho programa desde el xampp no me deja levantar mysql pero sí que me abre la ruta:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

En esta página sí que me aparecen las bases de datos creadas desde workbench, pero ya no me salen las que creé el año pasado.

¿Hay alguna manera de recuperar las bases de datos creadas el año anterior desde el phpmyadmin?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a ver.. tu pregunta tiene varios conceptos erroneos... si no te dejara levantar mysql, desde phpmyadmin no podrias ver las db, ya que el motor es mysql. Luego todo lo que hiciste el año pasado, donde lo guardaste? porque si estan en otro mysql, no se van a ver... Si podrias recuperarlas si levantas ese mysql que estabas usando el año pasado

Comment: phpmyadmin (con el login del usuario root) te muestra lo que contiene todo el mysql. Si no las ves allí es que ya no están. Tan solo podrías buscar por el disco a ver si las encuentras en cualquier formato que luego te permita recrearlas, pero si no las encuentras entonces dalas por perdidas (o busca copias de seguridad antiguas a ver si las ves por ahi)